# NullPointerException when adding a Jar to a Maven project

Tags: maven, jar, nullpointerexception

I was following answers from the stackoverflow question on adding local jar files to a Maven project.

I am using command line with the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\my-directory\myjar-123.jar -DgroupId=com.domain -Dartifact=myjar -Dversion=123 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

I am getting NullPointerException and running Maven with -X or -e switch doesn't make me any wiser.

Any advice as to what I'm doing wrong is much appreciated.

Thank you!